# Linux dual boot wiped Windows data

Tags: mount, dual-boot, data-recovery, unmounting

I have a Windows Vista/Debian Linux dual boot on my computer.  Yesterday I did a bunch of work on Windows, while Linux was hibernated.  Today I logged into Linux and tried to look at the data in the Windows partition.  It wasn't showing the new work I did on Windows, so I unmounted and re-mounted the Windows partition (seemed like a reasonable thing to do).  It still didn't show the new work.  So I logged off of Linux and booted Windows.  Now the work doesn't appear in Window either!  However, the work still shows up in the Windows "recent items" list, it's just that clicking on it generates an error about a broken link.

What is going on?  Is the data lost, and if so how do I prevent this from happening again?

Comment: Are you sure you left a properly saved copy of your work before leaving Windows? The items you're looking for may still be in Windows temporary folders, or in some application registers, yet these might have been lost when rebooting.

Comment: @JohnWHSmith The new work consisted of several folders containing word documents and pdf's.  Even the folders have disappeared.  As for the pdfs and word documents, both were saved in the usual way by MS Word, and I closed Word before shutting down Windows.

Comment: Tried an undelete/search of the drive? As in data recovery/carving? Or windows' chkdsk? Sounds more like a windows problem, unless you have a history of Debian destroying your data

Comment: Does your Linux installation have a swap partition?

Comment: @PM2Ring Yes, Linux has a swap partition (2 GB).  (Possibly relevant: The size of the swap is not always big enough to hibernate Linux.  Sometimes it complains that it can't hibernate because there isn't enough free swap.)